# 2D Vector A* Search

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, grid

I have a 2D vector that will read in a text file and sort of create a grid from the data contained within. The data in the text file will be that of "." "#" "*" symbols that will create a searchable A* search path. For this to work, the grid must be sized correctly.

Example 1:

[][][][][]

[][][][][]

[][][][][]

This would be correct as every row has the same amount of items and the columns line up nicely. An incorrect version would be if row 2 had more items than row 1 or row 3.

```
........
..#*....
..#.....
..#.####
..#.o...
```

If this were to be my text file of data, I would need to read in line by line and store that data within a VECTOR OF VECTOR in order to search it as a grid. To do this and keep it symmetrical like the example 1, I would need to constantly resize the vector in order to have the same amount of nodes stored. It cannot look like a stair case or anything less than a perfct four sided shape, aka a grid.

Within my code, instead of resizing based on the data size, (which I don't know how to calculate), I am resizing based on user input to test it.

```
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
   string fName = argv[1];
    string line = "";

    set < string > explored;

    vector < vector<  string> > mapData;

    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fName);

    if(!inFile)
    {
        cerr << "ERROR: Cannot open input file";
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }

    while(getline(inFile, line))
    {
        mapData[0].push_back(line);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mapData.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int z = 0; z < mapData[0].size(); z++)
        {
        cout << mapData[i][z] << endl;
        }
    }


    //vector<vector<int>> grid;
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    mapData.resize(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
    mapData[i].resize(b);
    for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
    {
       mapData[i][j].resize(2);
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

My output is a segmentation fault, I am very lost on how to proceed. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segmentation fault is caused by the line `mapData[0].push_back(line);`.
When you attempt access to mapData[0] it has not been initialized yet. The following solves your segmentation fault error, but I did not give thought to the rest of your code or algorithm.

```
vector<string> v;
mapData.push_back(v);
while(getline(inFile, line))
{
  mapData[0].push_back(line);
}
```